# Multi-line y label in plot

Tags: r, data-visualization

Is there a way to create multi-line labels for the y axis in an R plot?

I have tried adding a `\n` where the newline should be, but then the first line of the label gets clipped:

```
l <- 10
plot(0:l, (0:l), type='l',
     yaxt='n',
     xlab='Index',
     ylab='Cumulative sum\nof the sorted weights')
```

[image: Result of plot]

This happens both with the `tikzDevice` and inside RStudio. Also, I tried some of the `par()` options with no luck. How to do it properly?

(The oversized uper margin bothers me, too...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set the margins using `mar` or `mgp`:

```
l <- 10
op <- par(mar=c(5, 6, 4, 2) + 0.1)
plot(0:l, (0:l), type='l',
     yaxt='n',
     xlab='Index',
     ylab='Cumulative sum\nof the sorted weights')
par(op)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried using both `mar` and `mgp` in the call to `plot`. Was this too late?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? What do you mean by "too late"?

Comment: I am looking for a reason why the margin parameters were not recognized when I used them in the `plot` call. I didn't try `par` as in your code.

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't possible to change the margin width in the plot command.

Comment: ...that's always code for people to prove me wrong, which I'm sure will happen!

Answer (score 2):

Like @smillig suggested, you do it with `par`, changing the `mar` or `mgp` parameters.

But you have to call `par` **before** you call `plot`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that allows full control of the axis title is to use `mtext()`.

```r
l <- 10
plot(0:l, (0:l),
  type = "l",
  yaxt = "n",
  xlab = "Index",
  ylab = ""
)
mtext(side = 2, line = 3, "Cumulative sum")
mtext(side = 2, line = 2, "of the sorted weights")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>